# Physics engine or not for making a Pendulum in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to replicate the pendulum effect as seen in the old game "Gold miner", if you ever played it before. Do I need to use a physics engine for that, or not? I heard that Box2D is preferred over Chipmunk when it comes to ropes, but do I really have to join two objects together with a rope to accomplish this pendulum effect? I'd love to do it without a physics engine, but if I have to use one I think I would pref chipmunk as it comes with Cocos2d v3. (In short, whats the best way of making a pendulum that swings forever and can be lowered and raised) 
Im' a complete n00b when it comes to physics engines, never used one before, only made non-games apps before :/ Any help is very appreciated =)

Answer (score 0):

You mean the grappling hook in that game? That's absolutely not physics, or at least can be done easily without a physics engine. At best you may want to use the physicss engine's raycast collision detection methods (if any).

Comment: Nah, just setting the rotation directly because actions aren't ideal for frequently changing animations. For instance when the target rotation or position can change once every frame.

Comment: And how would I go about doing that? Not using actions I mean. Sorry for being so incompetent :/

Comment: sprite.rotation = 100; in its simplest form

Comment: Bu tis it possible to "animate" it so that it rotates slowly? like with the CCActionRotateTo method that lest you set the duration?

Comment: Check this out; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688817/how-to-continuously-run-my-pendulum-equation-in-cocos2d-objective-c/26689251#26689251