# How to continuously run my pendulum equation in cocos2d (Objective-C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I got a working equation for the rotation angle of my pendulum as seen in the code below:

```
const float gravity = 9.8;

float L = 0.01;

double CurrentTime = CACurrentMediaTime();

double angle = 120 * sin(sqrt((gravity/L)*CurrentTime));
```

But what I can't seam to figure out is how to make the sprite rotate continuously so that it acts just like a pendulum. I only make it move to the current value of the angle at the moment I click run, then it stopes when it reaches that position. Here is what I tried to do but only gave the result just explained:

`[_claw runAction:[CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCActionRotateTo actionWithDuration:3.0 angle:angle]]];`

So how do I make it rotate to the angle value continuously, so that it swings back and forth? Any help is highly appreciated :D

Comment: try to avoid mixing float and double in the same equation, either use double throughout or use CGFloat which is float on 32 bit and double on 64 bit systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
id rotation = [CCActionRotateTo actionWithDuration:3.0 angle:angle];

[_claw runAction:[CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:rotation, [rotation reverse], nil]]];
```

If reverse method not found

```
id rotation = [CCActionRotateTo actionWithDuration:3.0 angle:angle];
id reverseRotation = [CCActionRotateTo actionWithDuration:3.0 angle:_claw.rotation];
[_claw runAction:[CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:rotation, reverseRotation , nil]]];
```

Comment: The first example threw the exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CCIntervalAction: reverse not implemented.'

But the second one worked (Just had to change CCSequence to CCActionSequence) 

So thanks a lot man, u saved my day :)

Comment: @Shoaib i tired this code and it looks fine, but reverse action seems to be sudden movement, i mean, it slowly rotate to 45degree and reverse action in iPhone 6 plus and iPad pro is suddenly, in old device this code works fine.. i changed the CCROtate in CCAnimation interval to 64bit support. but somewhere something is missing.. can u help me?

Comment: @ICoder; can you share any sample code or video of the problem?

Comment: @Shoaib       const float gravity = 9.8f;
        
        float L = 0.01f;
        
        double CurrentTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
        
        double angle = 40.0f * sin(sqrt((gravity/L)*CurrentTime));
        
        id rotation = [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:3.0 angle:angle];
        id reverseRotation = [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:3.0 angle:sprhang.rotation];
        [sprhang runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:

Comment: @Shoaib [CCSequence actions:rotation, reverseRotation , nil]]];
      // [sprhang runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:rotation,reverseRotation], nil]]];
         [self addChild:sprhang];